# Install package on server but got SyntaxError

Tags: python, dask

I try to install dask with tar file on server but got the following error.

```
  File "setup.py", line 27
    if {'pytest', 'test', 'ptr'}.intersection(sys.argv):
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use a version of Python more recent than 11 years old?

Comment: This version of Python is given by the server. If this is the reason I probably can't use dask on  server.

Comment: `{'pytest', 'test', 'ptr'}` should be a variable first, and then you will be able to use it in the if condition. Ex. `var = {'pytest', 'test', 'ptr'}` , and then `if var.intersection(sys.argv): do something`

Comment: @OmAgarwal I just tried your solution. The problem comes from that comma between pytest and test.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able, in theory, to install packages on your server, then you are also able to install `conda`. Download and install [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) and use that to install Dask into a user directory, so that you can have the latest python with the best packages but without affecting the system version of python.

e.g.,

```
conda install dask
```

Comment: I can only install the package in my own directory trough tar command and then use it. Anyway, I will try your solution. Except this, is there any other solution?

Comment: Your python is too old to support Dask, the only way is to install a newer version, and conda is the easiest way to do that.